# ¿Cómo marcar una URl captada por una expresión regular?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un código para detectar una *URL* en un cuadro de texto (*Javascript*):

```
var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
var regex = new RegExp(expression);
var t = 'www.google.com';

if (t.match(regex)) {
  alert("Successful match");
} else {
  alert("No match");
}
```

Si la detecta realiza un `alert`. Mi problema es, ¿Cómo hacer que al detectarla, la marque como *URL* y si la cliqueas te lleve a esa *URL*? Es decir, que después de detectarla, haga eso que acabo de decir.

Comment: Es imposible poner un enlace en un alerta. ¿Dónde debería agregarse el enlace?

Comment: puedes usar el método `confirm()` en lugar de `alert()`, revisa el ejemplo que te deje, Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: @Eduardo en ningún momento se especifica en la pregunta dónde debería aparecer la URL *clickeable*. ¿Debería ser en una parte específica de tu página web?¿En dónde? Sin saber eso es imposible responderte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `match()` recibe una `Array` con los resultados obtenidos al comparar la **expresión regular** con una **cadena**, luego puedes usar el `Array` que en tu caso seria cargar la pagina web recibida.

Ejemplo:

```
var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
var regex = new RegExp(expression);
var t = 'pagina web www.google.com para búsquedas en internet';
var url = t.match(regex);
if (url) {
  document.body.innerHTML="<a target='_blank' href='http://"+url[0]+"'>"+url[0]+"</a>";
} else {
  alert("No match");
}
```

En el siguiente link podrás probarlo: https://jsfiddle.net/q191ppjp/

Comment: fwBasic, no quiero hacer eso quiero que una vez detectada la URl , me la marque como una URl y que sea cliqueable a su link, osea por ejemplo aca en StackOverflow, si coloco una url y la cliqueas te llevará a ese link, eso quiero hacer, que aparte de detectarla, también haga eso

Comment: Listo!... revisa nuevamente el ejemplo, y recuerda calificar la respuesta que mas se ajuste a tus requerimientos, Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: gracias fwBasic !! , nosé quien te puso el -1 ..

Comment: Tranquilo... no te preocupes, al parecer hay una mano oscura por ahí jajajaj!! ;))...

Answer (score 0):

No sé si es esto lo que buscas:

```
if (t.match(regex)) {
   alert("Successful match");
   document.write("<a href='//"+t+"'>"+t+"</a>");
} else {
   alert("No match");
}
```

Este código, además de la alerta, presentará en la página que se ejecute un enlace al contenido de la variable t.